# Computing $\int_{\Bbb{B}^3\times\Bbb{B}^3}\frac{\rm{d}^3x\,\rm{d}^3y}{\|x-y\|}=\frac{32}{15}\pi^2$, where $\Bbb{B}^3$ is the 3-dimensional unit ball

Tags: definite-integrals

Let's call $\mathbb{B}^3$ the three-dimensional unit ball, then how to compute the six fold
$$
\int_{\mathbb{B}^3\times \mathbb{B}^3}\frac{\text{d}^3x\,\text{d}^3y}{\|x-y\|}=\frac{32}{15}\pi^2
$$
I saw this question on a forum, but no one seemed willing to answer it so I put it here for help. Any useful help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your terminology, is $\Bbb{B}^3 \subset \Bbb{R}^3$ or $\Bbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Yes.

Comment: That wasn't a yes or no question

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm sorry, I misunderstood you, it's in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: You can simplify the computation by using the fact that the integral is rotation invariant, and so you can reduce the problem to where the first coordinate is on the positive x-axis.

Comment: You mean unit *ball*, not sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider a bit more general case of two balls with radii $a$ and $b$; for the convenience let's take $b>a$. Then the desired integral can be written in the form
$$I(a,b)=4\pi^2\int_0^\pi\sin \theta_1d\theta_1\int_0^b y^2dy\int_0^\pi\sin \theta d\theta\int_0^a \frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xy\cos\theta}}$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, and $\theta_1$ is the angle between $\vec y$ and axis Z (it means that we perform integration with respect to $\vec x$ first, and direct the Z' axis in polar system of coordinates along $\vec y$, and then perform integration with respect to $\vec y$).

Splitting the interval of integration ($x<y; x>y$), denoting $z=\cos \theta$, and integrating with respect to $\theta_1$,
$$=8\pi^2\int_0^by^2dy\int_{-1}^1dz\int_0^y\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xyz}}+8\pi^2\int_0^ay^2dy\int_{-1}^1dz\int_y^a\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2-2xyz}}$$
$$=8\pi^2\int_0^by\,dy\int_0^yx^2dx\int_{-1}^1\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-2\frac{x}{y}z+\frac{x^2}{y^2}}}+8\pi^2\int_0^ay^2dy\int_y^ax\,dx\int_{-1}^1\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-2\frac{y}{x}z+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}}$$
Then we can perform integration with respect to $z$, or just notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2rz+r^2}}$ is the generating function of Legendre' polynomials (and due to integration all polynomials die out, except for $P_0(z)=1;\,\int_{-1}^1P_0dz=2$).
We get
$$I(a,b)=16\pi^2\int_0^b\frac{y^4}{3}dy+16\pi^2\int_0^ay^2\frac{a^2-y^2}{2}dy=\frac{16\pi^2}{15}(a^5+b^5)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

We can focus on one integral first - in this case consider only

$$\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{d^3x}{|x-y|} = \int_{B(y,1)}\frac{d^3x}{|x|}$$

by translating the origin to the other variable. We can always rotate to a coordinate system for $x$ where $y$ always lies on the $x_3$ axis, giving us the equation of the ball

$$x^2-2|y|x_3 = 1-y^2$$

Converting to spherical coordinates, we obtain

$$r^2-2|y|r\cos\theta = 1-y^2 \implies \begin{cases}\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2+y^2-1}{2|y|r}\right)\\ r = |y|\cos\theta+\sqrt{1-y^2\sin^2\theta}\end{cases}$$

Of course this $\theta$ upper bound is only valid when $r>1-|y|$, so we need to split the integral into two

$$\int_{B(y,1)}\frac{r^2\sin\theta \: d(r,\theta,\varphi)}{r}$$

$$ = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1-|y|}\int_0^{\pi}r \sin\theta \:d\theta\:dr\:d\varphi + \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{1-|y|}^{1+|y|}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r^2+y^2-1}{2|y|r}\right)}r \sin\theta \:d\theta\:dr\:d\varphi$$

$$= 2\pi(1-|y|)^2 + 2\pi\int_{1-|y|}^{1+|y|}\frac{1-y^2}{2|y|}+r-\frac{r^2}{2|y|}\:dr$$

$$= 2\pi - 4\pi|y| + 2\pi y^2 +4\pi |y| - \frac{8\pi}{3} y^2 = 2\pi -\frac{2\pi}{3}y^2$$

We can plug that polynomial into the integral over a unit ball and get our final answer

$$2\pi\int_{B(0,1)}d^3y - \frac{2\pi}{3} \int_{\Bbb{S}^2}d\Omega \int_0^1 r^4\:dr  $$

$$= 2\pi\cdot\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)-\frac{2\pi}{3}\cdot(4\pi)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) = \boxed{\frac{32\pi^2}{15}}$$